# Change to SwiftUI state variable in for loop (UIKit) does not occur

Tags: swift, for-loop, uiview, swiftui

So I have a swift view as where the minimum example is something as follows (It is a UIView but for simplicity sake I'm going to make it a SwiftUI view):

```
class ViewName: UIView {

    
    @State var time: String = ""

    func setTime() {
        for place in self.data.places {
            print("the place address is \(place.address) and the representedobject title is \((representedObject.title)!!)")
            if (self.representedObject.title)!! == place.address {
                print("there was a match!")
                print("the time is \(place.time)")
                self.time = place.time
                print("THE TIME IS \(self.time)")
            }
        }
        print("the final time is \(self.time)")
    }

    var body: some View {
         //setTime() is called in the required init() function of the View, it's calling correctly, and I'm walking through my database correctly and when I print place.time, it prints the correct value, but it's the assignment self.time = place.time that just doesn't register. If I print place.time after that line, it is just the value ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference type is not allowed to be a SwiftUI View. We cannot do the following:

```
class ViewName: UIView, View {
  ...
}
```

[image: demo]

, so probably you meant this

```
struct ViewName: View {

    // ... other properties

    @State var time: String = ""

    func setTime() {
        for place in self.data.places {
            if self.representedObject.title == place.address {
                self.time = place.time
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
       Text("Some View Here")
         .onAppear {
            self.setTime()      // << here !!
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: No it's not a SwiftUI struct, it's a UIView and just has @State variables (which I thought were introduced in SwiftUI). Instead of onAppear, I run the function in the required init() that every UIView has. Sorry for the typo